# error on importing dump.sql into postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I recently exported a dump sql from a postgresql server and tried importing into my local installation. Both postgres versions are 9.3.5.

I keep getting an error and this process ends. The error is given below. Have tried it in windows and ubuntu and same error

```
psql:sites.sql:53670: invalid command \N
psql:sites.sql:53671: invalid command \N
psql:sites.sql:53672: invalid command \.
psql:sites.sql:53679: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 1: 1 1 AB25XC088 42.79236221 -73.87911224 0101000020E61000000D1...
```

Please help.

This question was marked as duplicate. But it is not as my copy simply does not happen. The command I run is:

```
psql -U postgres -f dump.sql <database_name>
```

Comment: please show us the relevant lines from the script and how you start the script. Are there any errors _before_ those that you have shown?

Comment: errors start from line psql:sites.sql:1: invalid command \N. Other than that I just exported a dump from postgresql server and imported into local postgresql server